# Menu layout in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with Bootstrap, and this is my first attempt. I am trying to have a menu on the left side of the page, but once we expand - I want the menu to be on top of the table. So.....I also have to to a 'transition animation' as well, which I have in css. I have been banging my head on a wall here for about two days, but cant seem to get it. Any advice on what I have done? The menu is going to the left - but it is on top of the table in the layout......

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: #E8E3E3;
}
.bgimage {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  color: #3279B6;
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
  background-color: #3279B6;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .item-list {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #686868;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
  .item-list div {
    transition: all 1.5s;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #686868;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Lewis Lab 1</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <header class="bgimage">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>My Todo App...</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="item-list">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVkTq.jpg" style="width: 20px">
          </div>
          <div class="item">Todos</div>
          <div class="item">Add</div>
          <div class="item">Edit</div>
          <div class="item">More</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <div>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Create TIme</th>
              <th>User Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Dog</td>
              <td>Walk the dog</td>
              <td>2 pm</td>
              <td>chris@thetraderguy.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>Feed the cat</td>
              <td>3:13 pm</td>
              <td>marketing@thetraderguy.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>School</td>
              <td>Do Lab 1</td>
              <td>6 pm</td>
              <td>signals@thetraderguy.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>Work out</td>
              <td>Go to gym</td>
              <td>7:15 pm</td>
              <td>chris@thetraderguy.com</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">

          <h1>Action Items</h1>
          <form>
            <label for="addTodo">Add Todo</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="addTodo" placeholder="Add Todo">
            <label for="details">Details</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="details" placeholder="Add details">
            <br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I get, not what I want:

[image: ...]

Answer (score 0):

There is one opened `<div>` tag, which hasn't been closed, under the `<table class="table table-striped">` tag. Firstly, please remove it.

Next, your problem is occurring when the resolution is less than 500px. Please, add the CSS block below:

```
.item-list .item {
   float:left;
   width: auto;
   padding: 10px;  
   background-color: #686868;
}
```

into the `@media all and (max-width: 500px){...}` media query.

You can check the added version from here: https://jsfiddle.net/pz19r40k/1/